# ffmpeg quits if one output stream fails - can this be prevented?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm responsible for maintaining a device that streams a live webcam feed to a remote relay server, and simultaneously writes a version of the stream to the local disk. It does this by a single instance of ffmpeg that has two outputs - one to the local disk, and one over rtsp to the streaming server

I'm encountering a problem where by if the streaming server disconencts for any reason, ffmpeg quits. I'm not really bothered if the live stream is lost, but it's a big problem that the local recording is lost also - it's not a huge detriment to the particular business process if it cannot be watched live, but losing the locally stored copy is a disaster

ffmpeg is started with a command line similar to:

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 4096 -async 1 -f v4l2 
  -input_format mjpeg -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 
  -i /dev/video0 -thread_queue_size 4096 -async 1 -f alsa 
  -i plughw:CARD=Set,DEV=0 -r 30 -c:a aac -b:a 96k -c:v h264 -b:v 983040 
  -profile:v baseline -preset veryfast -pix_fmt yuv420p 
  -f tee -map 0:v -map 1:a 
    [f=matroska]'/var/recordings/yyyy-mm-dd/backup.mkv'|
    [f=rtsp:rtsp_transport=tcp]rtsp://streamingserver.com:1234/session.sdp`
```

Is there any way (command line switch etc) that ffmpeg can be made to carry on if an output stream is lost, rather than quitting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the [onfail](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee) option.

```
[f=rtsp:onfail=ignore:rtsp_transport=tcp]
```

Ensure your ffmpeg version is recent.

Comment: In my case I had empty audio stream so it failed to encode the file. I had to use:
`ffmpeg -i inputfile.mp4 -map "0:v" -map "0:a?" -o outputfile.mp4` to include audio only if it could be included without errors.